# Connect to remote mssql with public ip

Tags: php, sql-server

I cannot connect to a remote mssql using

```
mssql_connect(xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename, $user, $password);
```

I also tried:

```
 - xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename,1433 
 - xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename,1434
 - xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename
 - xx.xx.xx.xx:1434
 - xx.xx.xx.xx:1433
 - xx.xx.xx.xx
```

None of them work. However, when I tried to connect the database with SQL Management Studio with my public ip, then it works(`xx.xx.xx.xx` or `xx.xx.xx.xx\instancename, 1433`) So I don't think there are any problems with ports. It also works when I created a local mssql database and connect to it with **php** by using **Local IP**, but doesn't work when I tried to connect to a remote mssql(different network) by using **WAN IP**. Does anyone know the cause for this or how to connect to a remote mssql with php? Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to connect from Linux machine and using MS ODBC Linux driver? Are you trying to connect from your web application? Did you set up sql server firewall to allow remote connections? Are you able to connect your SQL Server by using isql on CLI? All these assume you are on Linux.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a window server. Yes, I'm trying to connect from my web application(php). Firewall is properly setup, that why I can connect to it with SQL Management Studio and connect to the mssql with public ip.

Comment: Are you using PHP 7? Anything in the error logs? When you say `None of them work` are you getting access denied or a blank page?

Comment: Actually I wanted to learn if your PHP is working on Linux. In any case I would still double check firewall rules in SQL Server. Of course SQL Server user account as well.

Comment: No, I'm using php 5.2.9 with mssql driver enabled. the error said that it Unable to connect to server: xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: It works if I tried with my mssql local database though.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using Linux or connecting to it. I'm running PHP on XAMPP and trying to connect to mssql on a window server. Yes, my PHP is working.

Comment: My guess is that mssql driver in php doesn't let you connect remotely, only locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using the sqlsrv driver from Microsoft

```
$dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=xx.xx.xx.xx,1433;Database=xxxx",'user','password');
```

:)